# Simple Web Server is Python That Logs 1 IP ONLY and exits?

Tags: python, logging, webserver, ip, exit

I need help modifying this Python code that creates a Web server. I want it to log 1 IP address and then close the current web server.

This is the Python code i need help modifying:

```
PORT = 8080
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "Serving Port:", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

This is what happens when a connection has been made on the python web server:

> 192.168.0.10 - - [27/Dec/2014 18:48:30] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 200 -
>
> 192.168.0.10 - - [27/Dec/2014 18:48:31] code 404, message File not found

Problems made:

- IP logging is to detailed. (I just want the IP nothing else).
- 2 Connections have been made without the web server closing at 1 Connection.
- I also want the IP displayed with "**print**".

Does any one know how to do this??

Comment: So what have you tried so far? Have you read the docs for `SimpleHTTPServer`? Stack Overflow is not a code-writing service, it is for **specific** questions with **specific** answers. As it stands, this question is too broad.

Comment: Yes But I did not find anything that helps.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong place. For your homework you don't need a Web-Server, you need basic socket API.

Comment: @Daniel but a web browser will not recognise this.